# Returning parsed JSON array asynchronously

Tags: javascript, json, promise, async-await

I'm trying to parse a sample JSON and push the individual objects to an array. The problem I have is that I think it's working, but when calling `console.log` to print the resulting away, it returns an `undefined` value. I believe it's because I'm not handling my `async/await` requests properly, but I'm not sure how to not run the `console.log` function until all the elements have been pushed to my array.

**Attacks.js**

```
//Assume JSON output = {attack source, attack destination, attack type}

//Required modules
//@ts-ignore: undeclared module
//const watchStream = require('fs-watch-stream')
const es = require('event-stream')
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
const fs = require('fs');


async function initial(){
    var arr = [];
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('sample.json', {start: 3, encoding: 'utf8'});
    var parser = JSONStream.parse('employees.employee.*');
    stream.pipe(parser);

    parser.on('data', function (obj) {
        arr.push(obj);
    });

    parser.on('finish', async function(arr) {
        return(arr) = await Promise.resolve(arr);
    });
};

initial().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

**sample.json**

```
{
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Maria-Sharapova.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Downey Jr.",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think async and .then() mix.  Does "let arr = await initial()" work?

Comment: You can write a `console.log()` statement in the code itself. ex. `parser.on('data', function (obj) { arr.push(obj); });` next line can be `console.log(arr)`.

Comment: @DevOfZot In place of which line?

Comment: @zer00ne when doing that, it prints the array each time a piece of data is read. That results in printing 3 different arrays, each longer than the next. I want to only print the final result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part:

```
parser.on('finish', async function(arr) {
  return(arr) = await Promise.resolve(arr);
});
```

When the `finish` event is triggered the callback function `function(arr)` is called, but because it is a function, any `return` statement inside of it is not returned by `initial()` it is returned by `function(arr)` and there isn't any variable assigned to it so the value returned in `return(arr)` is lost. You're expecting that `initial()` resolves to `arr` but since the `return arr` statement is already inside `function(arr)` that returned value is lost and because `initial` doesn't have any `return` statement in the end it resolves to `undefined`. I think in this case the easier way is to go with a classic promise flow.

```
function initial(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      var arr = [];
      var stream = fs.createReadStream('sample.json', {start: 3, encoding: 'utf8'});
      var parser = JSONStream.parse('employees.employee.*');
      stream.pipe(parser);

      parser.on('data', function (obj) {
        arr.push(obj);
      });

      parser.on('finish', function(arr) {
        resolve(arr);
      });
   }) 
};

initial().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

Comment: The JS code compiles with no errors, however I'm not getting any output at all. Perhaps the array isn't returning properly?

Comment: That's because there isn't anything wrong in the code, is just that your function doesn't do what you need it to do. As you say the array isn't returning properly I updated my answer, hope to make this clearer

Comment: I see, I must not be pushing/piping to the array properly then.

Comment: Just a heads up, I figured it out. In my `parser.on('finish', function(arr) {` line, remove `arr` in place of blank parentheses. I guess `arr` is already defined, so passing in `arr` again would cause me to lose the values. Appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply defines a event handler; your `initial` function will not wait for the delegate to even execute, never mind complete:

```
parser.on('finish', async function(arr) {
    return(arr) = await Promise.resolve(arr);
});
```

You should wrap the handler in a `Promise`, which can be awaited by `initial`:

```
await Promise(resolve => parser.on("finish", resolve));
```